# Wordpress Migration issue css

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated website to new domain, the problem is css not loading
if I inspect element it gives link to old domain, is there a way to update css links in wordpress?

please help

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving a WordPress site to a new domain, you need to change the **Site URL** and **Home URL**, usually in the database or in `wp-config.php`, depending on how the site was originally set up. There may be other changes you need to make in the database, or by manually editing posts, like the locations of images in posts.

This page on wordpress.org is a good reference, for all the things you may need to change, and it shows a few different methods to make most of the changes, so you can choose the one you prefer:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Make sure to keep a backup of the site in case of any mistakes. If you make some changes, and most of the site is working, but a few things aren't, I would recommend making another backup, so you could restore it again without losing much work, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

yes when you are adding links to your site you show use the function site_url().example/my_post in order to construct the links