# After domain change WordPress website became broken. (css)

Tags: css, wordpress, url, dns

The old domain was https://pitypangvendeghaz.com, the new is https://pitypangvendeghaz.hu. The css of the site became ugly, and I can not find a solution.

Can anybody help me what is the problem? I tried all of the steps which are recommended after domain change.

Comment: Have you checked the hardcoded references in your templates/plugins?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993068/edit) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Migration issue css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455910/wordpress-migration-issue-css)

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you didn't move your files correctly.
[errors in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAd3M.png)

Move you folder with videos and pictures. And also move your file

```
/wp-content/uploads/tc_stylesheets/hotel-wp.1558556385.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to appearance -> theme editor  and then copy the css in style.css